# How to force HTML elements to be left aligned and not wrap

Tags: html, css, css-float, whitespace

My question is very similar to 
[Force float left with no line break no matter what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556250/force-float-left-with-no-line-break-no-matter-what) but I'm not using tables

https://jsfiddle.net/hkzvo8h7/

I have a the following layout (shortened)

```
<div>
<span>
item1
</span>
<span>
item1
</span>
<span>
item1
</span>    
</div>
```

Nothing else. The CSS floats each `span` element and I'm hoping to have a long, single row of items floating horizontally.

The issue I have is, as soon as the element reaches the end of the page, it wraps. I would rather the page's width extends.

To simulate this, I've wrapped my `span` in a `div`:

```
div {
  max-width:350px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:scroll;
}


span{
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color:#fe3e4a;
}
```

As per other posts, I've also included the `white-space:nowrap` attribute.

What I'm seeing is:

```
item1
item1
item1
item1  
etc
```

or (depending on the width of the parent div or width of each span)

```
item1    item1    item1
item1    etc
```

where as what I'm trying to achieve is (with no wrap but with scroll bar)

```
item1    item1    item1    item1    item1    item1    item1    item1    item1    item1    item1    item1    etc
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You can use `display: inline-block` on the span elements or `display: flex` on the parent where direction is row by default. Is that what you are after? https://jsfiddle.net/phj4ewbt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`white-space: nowrap;` only works with `inline` and `inline-block` elements

if you remove the floats from the spans and display inline-block it works as intended!

`span{
  float: none; // don't really need this line, just remove the float!
  display: inline-block;
}`

An updated version of your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w3uk99gz/

*Update:* **Yes** you can use `div`s instead of `span`s.

This is an example using different types of elements: https://jsfiddle.net/w3uk99gz/2/ all together

Comment: Would this answer be valid if the span was actually a div?

Comment: replacing `span` with `div` alone won't work - you'll have to *inline* them using `inline-block`...

Comment: yes you can set a `div` to `display: inline-block;` and will still be valid

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to *float* the `span` (floating containers *wraps*) - remove it and set to and *inline* `display`. See demo below where I have set `span` to `inline-block`:

```css
div {
  max-width: 350px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

span {
  /*float: left;*/
  display: inline-block; /* ADDED */
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #fe3e4a;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a flex solution - we shouldn't need to float anything in this day and age of css:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
  <span>item1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a +1 but as this doesn't really answer the question (as it shows an alternative) although it *will* be the solution I eventually go for! I keep forgetting about `flex`!